# ListView inside a Row with dynamic width

Tags: flutter

I want to create a `ListView` and a `Button` to add items to the `ListView`.

```
             Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        Conversation conversation = teamMembers[index];
                        return SizedBox(
                          width: 42,
                          height: 42,
                          child: Avatar(
                            name: member.name,
                            profileUrl: member.profileUrl,
                            radius: 38,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      itemCount: teamMembers.length,
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      _showSheet();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 42,
                      height: 42,
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xfff2f2f2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28)),
                      child: Icon(Icons.add),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
```

I'm getting the results as below for lesser number of items and more number of items. How can I make the + button closer to the ListView even if the list length is less.

[image]

Comment: one way is to add the button inside the listView

Comment: but in that case, the button will also get outside the view and only visible after some scroll if the items are more.

Comment: i think you have to create custom ListView, as there is no way to change it's properties.

Comment: use `Flexible`.

Comment: With `Flexible` with `fit: FlexFit.loose` which is the default one solves the problem. 
***If the fit is FlexFit.loose, the child can be at most as large as the available space (but is allowed to be smaller).***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue is replacing the Expanded widget with Flexible widget.

Expanded actually is just a shorthand for Flexible. Flexible takes only the needed space, and Expanded takes all available space, respecting the flex factor.

Flexible with `fit: FlexFit.loose` which is the default one solves the problem. If the fit is `FlexFit.loose`, the child can be at most as large as the available space (but is allowed to be smaller)

So,

```
Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        Conversation conversation = teamMembers[index];
                        return SizedBox(
                          width: 42,
                          height: 42,
                          child: Avatar(
                            name: member.name,
                            profileUrl: member.profileUrl,
                            radius: 38,
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      itemCount: teamMembers.length,
                    ),
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      _showSheet();
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 42,
                      height: 42,
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          color: Color(0xfff2f2f2),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28)),
                      child: Icon(Icons.add),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              )
```

- is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Widget> _buttons = [];

Wrap(
  spacing: 12.0, // horiz
  runSpacing: 12.0, // vert
  crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.start,
  alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
  children: _buttons,
),
```

Comment: While your code may provide a solution to the problem, please refrain from posting code-only answers. Always try and provide an explanation as to how/why the code you suggest will help the OP solve their problem. Code doesn't always provide a clear and indicative answer, and doesn't share knowledge and troubleshooting skills very well.